# How can I prevent this unexpected UICollectionView behaviour when paging is enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am seeing behavior in my `UICollectionView` that I don't understand, and would like to prevent.

I have a `UICollectionView` with a bunch of custom cells in it. It horizontally scrolls, and it has paging enabled. I have `allowsSelection`, `allowsMultipleSelection`, and `scrollsToTop` = NO.

I have single & double tap `UITapGestureRecognizer`s on each cell.

I have the `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate method returning NO, as I'm managing the actions taken on the cells through these gesture recognizers.

Here's what happens- When I tap the last cell that is furthest to the right in the collection view, it scrolls backwards (to the left) automatically, takes the item that I just selected off screen and is no longer visible, and THEN fires the gesture recognizer handler.

If I look at `myCollectionView.visibleCells` inside my gesture recognizer selector, I see that the cell is not contained in there, as it's been scrolled off screen.

This only happens when paging is enabled- if I turn it off and tap the last item, everything works as expected and no automatic scrolling backwards occurrs.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it??? I'd like the same behaviour to take place with and without paging enabled, but can't right now.

How can I prevent UICollectionView automatically scrolling before gesture recognizer selector is called?

**EDIT**

If I subclass my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override:

```
-(CGSize) collectionViewContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(10000, CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame));
}
```

set to an arbitrarily high number, the automatic scrolling backwards does not occur. Looks like this is happening due to `contentSize`?

Comment: I seem to be running into the same issue - did you ever find a fix for your problem? It appears it only happens if the page size is less than 50% of the collectionView.frame.width...

Comment: Yeah, noticed the same thing as well. Didn't end up spending too much more time on it as we went with a non-paged solution. If you find out anything I'll take a look. Cheers

Comment: Did you find solution to fix this issue?